# Running total with condition in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, cumulative-sum

I have the following 2-column table:

```
Threshold  Duration
1          1
1          2
1          1
0          1
0          2
1          1
1          3
```

I would like to create a column with running total of 'Duration' column which would start from 0 whenever the value of 'Threshold' column changes i.e.:

```
Threshold  Duration  Total 
1          1         1
1          2         3
1          1         4
0          1         1
0          2         3
1          1         1
1          3         4
```

Thanks

Comment: Where is your attempt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This formula should do the trick:

```
=IF(A2<>A1,B2,B2+C1)
```

For example, with your sample data laid out as below:

[image: img]

Answer (score 0):

I think Ashleedawh got this right and did a better answer than me. I quickly was working on my own solution and will provide it anyway, just so you can see a little bit of variation.

`Threshold  Duration     Total       Formula I used
    1              1              1        =C3
    1              2              3        =IF(B4-B3<>0,C4,D3+C4)
    1              1              4        =IF(B5-B4<>0,C5,D4+C5)
    0              1              1        =IF(B6-B5<>0,C6,D5+C6)
    0              2              3        etc.... use click and drag....
    1              1              1 
    1              3              4`

for my version to work I had to make a specific formula in the first row of '=C3' the used a similar formula to Ashlee's above.

Just thought I would post to see if it also helps....
Here is a screen capture of my work, I stated in Cell B2 - so the word Threshold is in cell B2.

[Screen Capture Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JJb8o.jpg)